# OSX: Android studio emulator not showing up in adb devices or Logcat window

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I am currently on Android Studio 3.0.1 and OSX 10.13.1

[This is a screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbdCX.jpg)

I have tried all the following things:

1. killing and starting adb server (adb kill-server and adb start-server)
2. Enable and Disable adb integration with android studio
3. Added android-sdk/platform-tools and /tools paths to ~/.bash_profile
4. I have created multiple emulators - wiped their data, etc
5. Have unistalled/installed android sdk platform tools multiple times; even done the same with HAXM installer
6. restart android studio and my system

The interesting thing is that I can see the devices
 when I connect to deviceConnect (https://mobilelabsinc.com/resources/videos/deviceconnect-demo)
This software was closed while I was trying out with the emulator, I have checked in activity monitor too to make sure.

I still cannot see my emulator in either "adb devices" or logcat window.

Side Note: I see here: ~/.android/avd/: the emulators that I have created, I feel somehow this needs to be linked to the android avd? I have spent wayyy too much time on this!!

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by the deviceConnect/deviceBridge tool from mobilelabsinc that you are using. You only have one option: uninstall the deviceConnect/deviceBridge tool.

Just moving the deviceConnect/deviceBridge tool to the trash will not work. You will need to use a tool like AppCleaner(https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to remove it. Once you have removed the tool, it should solve your problem (Might need a reboot!).

Comment: I cannot remove it as I need it for testing. Still I had tried that, but that does not help. :(